# Cannot get object from Session

Tags: web-services, spring-security, restful-authentication, jsessionid

I have the following scenario:

1. I access to a web application - that makes use of spring security, create an object in session, let us say a cart with some entries.
2. I access the application using a restful client. I do have: user, password, JSESSIONID cookie with its corresponding value. Both are using basic authentication.

The result? I get the object - the cart on this case - but it comes empty. It does not have the entries that were added. It is almost like - even though I was able to authenticate successfully there is a mechanism in place that creates a new instance of the object, instead of giving me the existing one.

Do you have any idea of spring security is somehow not allowing this to happen.

I also noticed that... I send the Cookie JSESSIONID=Number and when it responds it gives me a different Number for JSESSIONID, my assumption is that even though I have the wright credentials and it allows me to log in, it does not allow me to use the same session, it simply creates a new one and my cart is empty there.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you send the same cookie? Please use Fiddler to ensure you send the same JSESSIONID

Comment: Did you see the answer below? Was it helpful?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments Michael! I am currently testing Fiddler and I will let you know how it went.

Answer (score 0):

SpringSecurity replaces JSESSIONID cookie after the authentication (and it is strongly recommended not to disable the feature to prevent the Session Fixation attack).
The following configuration enables the feature

```
<http ...>
    ...
    <session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession" />
</http>
```

To copy the the existing session attributes use `migrateSession`.

The attributes values according to the documentation http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#session-mgmt :

- migrateSession - creates a new session and copies the existing session attributes to the new session. This is the default.
- none - Don't do anything. The original session will be retained.
- newSession - Create a new "clean" session, without copying the existing session data.

Answer (score 0):

Spring creates a new session on authentication. This is called Session Fixation Protection. Read more about it here:

- http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/ns-config.html#ns-session-fixation

Comment: Thank you very much Kevin. I already removed the protection for that by doing the following: <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="none" /> Here is what I am doing: 1.- Access the web app, 2.- Get the value for the JSESSIONID cookie, 3.- Access with a RESTFul client, using the same credentials, authentication (basic) and I send the JSESSIONID cookie with the value I got at 2. But still, even though I can authenticate it always creates a new session and therefore my cart comes back empty. Any idea of how to overcome this? Thanks again for your kind help!

Comment: Can you share your spring security configuration?